# Phone Number Validation. Allow only 0 as first digit

Tags: jquery, validation

i have a phone number validation where only numbers are allowed on keypress and first number should be 0.
this is my jquery script:

```
jQuery("#phone-number").keypress(function(ev){
    var x = document.getElementById("phone-number").value;
    // Don't ignore numbers.
    if ((ev.charCode >= 64 && ev.charCode <= 91) || (ev.charCode >= 96 && ev.charCode <= 123) && x.charAt(0)!="0" ) {
                alert("it should start with 0 ");
                return false;
    }

});
```

`x.charAt(0)!="0"` is not working as any number can be passed as 1st digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone-number"/>
```

```js
$(document).on('input','#phone-number',function(){
    var phone=$('#phone-number').val();
   if(phone.indexOf('0')!==0){
     alert('First number must be 0');
     $('#phone-number').val('');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```js
// Just for demonstration. You can use it your way.
jQuery("#phone-number").keypress(function(ev){
    var x = $(this).val();
    
    if (ev.keyCode < 48 || ev.keyCode > 57) {
      alert("You should only enter numbers.");
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

});

// Add the keyup event and check with the regex.
jQuery("#phone-number").keyup(function(ev){
    var x = $(this).val();
    
    // Allow Backspace and Delete
    if (ev.keyCode == 8 || ev.keyCode == 46) {
      return true;
    }
    
    if (!x.match(/^0+/)) {
      alert("The first digit should be 0");
      $(this).val(x.substr(0,-1));
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="phone-number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this Regex Pattern to input .

```
<input id="phone-number" type="text" pattern="[0][0-9]{9}" />
```

this `pattern="[0][0-9]{9}"` means first digit should be 0 , then remaining 9 digits are between 0 to 9

here `{9}` is length of digits after first 0.

Comment: i have seen this answer almost everywhere, but this dosent work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it before form submit with the pattern like below

```
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(){
        var value = $('#phone-number').val()
        var regex = new RegExp(/^\+?[0][0-9(),.-]{9}$/);
        if(value.match(regex)) {return true;}
          return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two regular expressions to replace non-zero starting characters and other non-digits. To do it while typing, I used keyup (since keypress happens before the textbox value includes the most recent character):

```
$('#phone-number').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(
        $(this).val()
            .replace(/^[^0]*/, '') // Remove starting non-zero characters
            .replace(/[^\d]*/g, '') // Remove non-digit characters
        );
    }
);
```